# galasso - Error: Every 'y' should be a numeric vector

Tags: r-mice, lasso-regression

I am very new to R and want to use `galasso` for variable selection with multiple imputation. I followed strictly the introduction and example but I could not solve the last puzzle when I run the command. I compare all the vectors and lists with those from the example and cannot find where the mistake comes from.

```
mydata <- rpdata %>%
  select("v1":"v36", "rp_score")

# Using the mice defaults for sake of example only.
mids <- mice(mydata, m = 5, method="cart", printFlag = FALSE)

# Generate list of completed data.frames
dfs <- lapply(1:5, function(i) complete(mids, action = i))

# Generate list of imputed design matrices and imputed responses
x <- list()
y <- list()
for (i in 1:5) {
  x[[i]] <- as.matrix(dfs[[i]][, paste0("v",1:36)])
  y[[i]] <- dfs[[i]]$rp_score
}

#Calculate observational weights  
#weights <-1-rowMeans(is.na(miselect.df)) 
pf <-rep(1,36) 
adWeight<-rep(1,36)

fit <- cv.galasso(x,y, pf,adWeight)
```

Here is the error:

> Error in galasso(x, y, pf, adWeight, family, nlambda, lambda.min.ratio,  :
> Every 'y' should be a numeric vector.